# node.js/ strings which meet regex

Tags: node.js

I have a list of string in node.js

```
var listStr = ["helloworld","helloworld1","helloworld2","somethingelse"]
```

I want to find all strings which meet some regex. For example, for the regex: `*world*`, I would get the next strings: `"helloworld","helloworld1","helloworld2"`

there is any npm package or function which get a list of strings and regex, and return the strings which meet the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an NPM package for this:

```
var filtered = listStr.filter(function (item) {
    return item.match(/world/);
});
```

Contents of `filtered`:

```
[ 'hello world',
  'helloworld1',
  'helloworld2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain JavaScript. Just fix your regex, and use `Array#filter()`:

```
listStr.filter(function(str){return /.*world.*/.test(str)})
                                     ^^     ^^ proper wildcard
```